# Spring data mongo repository find by any field

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I wonder if it is possible to find an object list by any field.
Something like below?

```
public interface MyRepo extends MongoRepository<MyObject,String>{
    List<MyObject> findByAnyField(String query);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not supported by Spring Data MongoDB. Derived repository query methods support either regular or geo queries.

You can implement find-by-any field yourself, see [Searching for value of any field in MongoDB without explicitly naming it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790819/searching-for-value-of-any-field-in-mongodb-without-explicitly-naming-it)