# How to find the data from collection according to url in golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm retrieving the data from the database when the user hit the url like `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer?keyword=dhiman`  then it search for the data in the collection if there is any field matches then it will retrieve that data. if the user entered the short url like  `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer?keyword=dhi` then it also retrieve the data which matches like that how I'll solve this problem. I tried the code for this like following:-

Struct of the customer

```
type Customer struct {
  Id               int    `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
  FirstName        string `json:"first_name" bson:"first_name"`
  LastName         string `json:"last_name" bson:"last_name"`
  Email            string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
  PhoneNumber      string `json:"phone_number" bson:"phone_number"`
}
type Customers []Customer
```

Functions

```
func GetCustomers(c *gin.Context) {
value := c.Query("keyword")
fmt.Println(value)
response := ResponseControllerList{}
conditions := bson.M{"last_name":value}
data, err := models.GetCustomerListing(conditions)
if err != nil {
    response = ResponseControllerList{
        config.FailureCode,
        config.FailureFlag,
        config.FailureMsg,
        nil,
        nil,
    }
} else {
    response = ResponseControllerList{
        config.SuccessFlag,
        config.SuccessFlag,
        config.SuccessMsg,
        data,
        // dataCount,
        nil,
    }
}
GetResponseList(c, response)
}
```

GetCustomerListing function in models page:-

```
func GetCustomerListing(customerQuery interface{}) (result Customers, err error) {
mongoSession := config.ConnectDb()
sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
defer sessionCopy.Close()
getCollection := mongoSession.DB(config.Database).C(config.CustomerCollection)
err = getCollection.Find(customerQuery).Select(bson.M{"password": 0}).All(&result) //.Skip(skip).Limit(limit)
if err != nil {
    return result, err
}
return result, nil
}
```

collection images

[image]

Comment: What problems / errors are you having? What is the definition of the `Customers` type?

Comment: @icza i edit my question

Comment: Please answer the other questions too: what problems / errors are you having?

Comment: It retrieve the data when user enter the last name but if it enter the first name then it does not retrieve the data I want if user enter any field data then it retrieve the data which matches like it for example `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer?keyword=puneet` then it matches with collection `first_name` and retrieve it @icza

Comment: This questions looks like it could read: "In mongodb how do I query, multiple fields and/or perform a SQL LIKE filter". If that is the question, simply querying SO will yield an answer. The URL, web ness of the question does not seem relevant.

Comment: See related question: [Searching for value of any field in MongoDB without explicitly naming it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790819/searching-for-value-of-any-field-in-mongodb-without-explicitly-naming-it).

Comment: @icza see i found my answer thankyou. for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer it is done by using the `$or` in mongodb.

In the monogdb there is a operator called or `$or` it checks the value with all the fields and produce result.

There is a `bson.RegExis` used. Because it will matches or checks the data similar to it receives from the user.

There is change in condition. The condition is:-

```
conditions := bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{
    bson.M{"first_name": bson.RegEx{value,""}},
    bson.M{"last_name": bson.RegEx{value,""}},
    bson.M{"email": bson.RegEx{value,""}},
    bson.M{"phone_number": bson.RegEx{value,""}},
}}
```

there is change in the query