# Find all occurrences of elements in an array in a string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have documents akin to the following format:

[image: img1]

When a user performs a search, they send an array to the backend. This array contains at least one element.

Say that they send `['javascript']` to the backend. Is there a way to query MongoDB to find out with documents contain the word `javascript`?

I tried something like,

`db.find({ body: { $all:['javascript'] } });`

but that only works if `body` is an array as well. Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you need to search all fields, you might try creating a text index https://stackoverflow.com/a/35843354/11746212

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a field contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a **pipe-delimited** regex pattern with the keywords list like this:

```
const subStrings = ["javascript", "php", "python"];
const regex = subStrings.join("|");


 db.find ({
   body: { $regex: regex, $options: 'i' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$regex` operator and pass it a regex contained in a string:

```
db.find({ body: { $regex: ".*javascript.*" }});
```

You could also do this:

```
db.find({ body: /.*javascript.*/ });
db.find({ body: /javascript/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a text index on the fields you want to search on. If you want to search on all fields

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

Or if you want to include only few specific fields, than

```
db.collection.createIndex( { title: "text", body: "text" } )
```

You can add weightage also, for eg. in your case title should be having more weightage than description.

Then you can have a search like:

```
db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "java javascript python" } } )
```

this will search for all documents which contains any or all these words.