# How to check if a value exists anywhere in an entire MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I know you could do `Coll.findOne({ email_1: 'abc@somedomain.com' })` to look up *abc@somedomain.com* against the field *email_1* in collection *Coll*. However, what if there were several email fields (*email_1*, *email_2*, *email_3*, etc.) and I needed to look up a given email against all those fields?

I could reiterate `Coll.findOne({ email_1: 'abc@somedomain.com' })` for each field in my collection but that obviously isn't most optimal.

Comment: A similar question like your. [Just look it] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790819/searching-for-value-of-any-field-in-mongodb-without-explicitly-naming-it). May be helpful.

Comment: As far as I know I'm not aware of anything, unless we do it in code. Interested to learn if someone has a query solution.

Comment: I believe that, if possible in your case, the best way would be changing the schema to something like `"emails": ["email1@test.com","email2@test.com","email3@test.com"]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for value of any field in MongoDB without explicitly naming it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790819/searching-for-value-of-any-field-in-mongodb-without-explicitly-naming-it)