# How to efficiently find documents by various criteria in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of books with documents laid out like

```
{
   "title": "The book",
   "author": "Joe Bob",
   "tags": ["dogs", "funny", "race"],
   "categories": ["fiction", "adventure"]
}
```

I would like to use one search bar to find a book by any of these criteria. I've got this down for the most part, but I don't understand now if it is a search or aggregation I should be using. I also wish I could have everything be case insensitive but I cannot figure out how to do something similar to `$options: 'i'` with an `$in` operator.

```
$or : [
    {'title': {$regex: search, $options: 'i'}},
    {'author': {$regex: search, $options: 'i'}},
    {'tags': {$in: [search]}},
    {'categories': {$in: [search]}},
]
```

Is this the best way for me to search through 100s of documents like this? Or should I prefer aggregate.

Comment: Take a look at the [Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) - since you are searching all the fields.

Comment: You can use:
`{'tags':  { $elemMatch: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } }` to search in arrays by regex

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, you have this thing thing pretty much figured out, save for the case insensitivily for those arrays, which I will get to in a moment.

First off, I suggest that you follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35843354/1927991) to searching all fields. However, if you want to stick to your method, which is also perfectly valid, here is how I would alter your query.

Since arrays are matched the same way strings are, you don't really need the `$in` operator there at all. So making those `categories` and `tags` searches case-insensitive is a trivial matter. Let's say we're looking for "Mark", so anything with "marketing" in the `categories` should get picked up. Here is how:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "title": {
        $regex: "Mark",
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "author": {
        $regex: "Mark",
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "tags": {
        $regex: "Mark",
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "categories": {
        $regex: "Mark",
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    
  ]
})
```

And here is a [Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qxZ2Egigya2) for you to test it.