# Is it possible to do a wildcard search using mongoose in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to do a wildcard search on the Whole collection, irrespective of the Columns or rows.

| ID | Name | Subject | Expert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Hill | Science | Maths |
| 2 | Matt Jane | English | Spanish |
| 3 | Tom Hill | Maths | Chemistry |

1.

```
   mongoose.connection.db.collection('CollectionName').find({"name":/Hil/}).toArray(function (err,data){});
```

I get both ID **1** and **3**

I tried using the $text $search function after indexing the collection

2.

```
   mongoose.connection.db.collection('CollectionName')find({$text:{$search:"Maths"}}).toArray(function (err,data){});
```

I get both ID **1** and **3**

3.

```
   mongoose.connection.db.collection('CollectionName')find({$text:{$search:/Mat/}}).toArray(function (err,data){});
```

The above doesn't work.

I want to perform a wildcard search on both the column and row something like .find("wildcard":"wildcard")

Is it possible to achieve the above ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `$or` with regex pattern?

```js
const match = /Mat/;

const query = collection.find({
    $or: [{ name: match }, { subject: match }, { expert: match }],
});
```

Comment: 1. I might not know the column names, as it is generated dynamically
2. If I have 50+ column then the above would be a tedious process

Comment: Sounds like it is not possible with plain mongodb. You can read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790819/searching-for-value-of-any-field-in-mongodb-without-explicitly-naming-it