# MongoDB/pymongo: Check for a string in a collection of arbitrary length with unknown keys

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to search for a particular value in a series of key/value pairs of arbitrary length and keys in a collection. An example collection:

```json
{
    'myJsonObject' : {
        'key1' : 'value1',
        'key2' : 'foobar',
        'key3' : 'value3'
    }
}
```

I want to run a query which returns `True` if and only if it finds the string `'foobar'` in any of an arbitrary number of key/value pairs. If working with a python dict, I would write something like:

```python
myJsonObject = {
    'key1' : 'value1',
    'key2' : 'foobar',
    'key3' : 'value3'
}

def check_for_foobar(aDict):
    for value in aDict.values():
        if 'foobar' == value:
            return(True)
    return(False)

print(check_for_foobar(myJsonObject))
```

In this case the function will return `True` because `foobar` is one of the values.
Is there an analogous way to check every value of a json object of arbitrary length and keys like this in mongodb or pymongo? I am told that the [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator could be helpful.
Thank you for any help or guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching for value of any field in MongoDB without explicitly naming it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790819/searching-for-value-of-any-field-in-mongodb-without-explicitly-naming-it)