# PyMongo search on multiple fields

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am creating a small application, where my user are hosted into a MongoDB server. My application is in Python, so I'm using the pymongo driver.

The structure of my users looks like this :

```json
{
  "id": "1",
  "username": "username",
  "mail": "mail@mail.com",
}
```

On my API, I want to have a GET route that look like this :

```bash
http://api.lan/api/v1/users/{user_info}
```

Where user_info can be any of the following MongoDB document field: id, username, mail.

Today, with using the pymongo driver, I'm only able to search in my collections by searching on a specific field, like so :

```py
self._users.find_one("username": "username")
```

But I would love to be able to search without having to tell the `find_one()` method about the username field, and just to search in the `users` collection any document where a field is equal to a given string.

If someone knows how I can achieve that, I would appreciate !

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching for value of any field in MongoDB without explicitly naming it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790819/searching-for-value-of-any-field-in-mongodb-without-explicitly-naming-it)